# Sequelize conditional on upsert

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm currently using sequelize v5 with node.js. I'm trying to use upsert to create new rows or update existing ones, but I want the update to trigger only if a condition is met.

```
await Model.upsert({values});
```

In the model table I have a boolean column. I want the update to not overwrite the existing row if the boolean is true. I figured maybe I can use a hook for beforeUpdate or beforeSave but I couldn't figure it out.

Edit: I'm using postgresql if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

let say you have model called `User`
you declared model class

```
class User extends Model {}
User.init({
  username: DataTypes.STRING,
  mood: {
    type: DataTypes.ENUM,
    values: ['happy', 'sad', 'neutral']
  }
});
```

you can ad hooks like that

```
User.beforeUpsert(user, options) => {
  if(user.condition){
... do stuff
  }
});
```

Comment: How would I prevent the upsert if that condition isn't met there? From my understanding with that hook I can do other methods, but the upsert would still go through after the methods are complete. I could be wrong since I haven't used hooks very much yet.

Comment: you can stop execute the function when condition by return;

Comment: ```
if (condition) return;
```

Answer (score 0):

For upsert operation in the v5 there is already a **`beforeUpsert`** hook, try that maybe will be helpfull.

Here is the [official docs](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/hooks.html) for Sequelize v5 where you can find all the hooks and their usage